# Django REST framework - Serializer relations User.username

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im working on a django project, and I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug            = models.SlugField(unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object  = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    parent          = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content         = models.TextField()
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CommentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

---

I use this serializer:

```
class CommentDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerMethodField()
    replies = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'replies',
            'timestamp'
        ]
    def get_user(self,obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)

    def get_replies(self,obj):
        if obj.is_parent:
            return CommentChildSerializer(obj.children(),many=True).data
```

---

for this view:

```
class CommentDetailApiView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

---

here is the PostSerializer I use,

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerMethodField()
    comments = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'user',
            'title',
            'content',
            'comments'
        ]
    def get_user(self,obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)

    def get_comments(self,obj):
        comments_qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj)
        comments = CommentSerializer(comments_qs, many=True).data
        return comments
```

---

this is what I get in the PostDetailAPIView:

---

```
{
    "user": "abc",
    "title": "blabla",
    "content": "bla",
    "comments": [
        {
            "user": 1,
            "content": "hey",
            "timestamp": "2020-02-18T00:07:29.932850Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

How do I get the comment user username instead of its id?

I get the username of the comment user only in the `CommentDetailApiView`.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [`serializers.StringRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `get_user` method to the `CommentSerializer` and now it works:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'timestamp'
        ]
    def get_user(self,obj):
        return str(obj.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `UserSerializer` to indicate what you want to show of the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

class CommentDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    ..... # the rest of your code
```

Comment: Did you change the serializer used in the user? I mean this line `user = UserSerializer()`

Comment: yes, I build a new `UsernameSerializer` and set it to the user field in the `CommentDetailSerializer`, but nothing changes

Comment: I get the username of the comment users in the CommentListAPIView. I tried to change the RetrieveAPIView to a ListAPIView but still no username in the CommentDetailAPIView

Comment: What is it that you are logging? Where does the 'title' comes from? Maybe if you have other views you can post them also

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `to_representation()` function just like below:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    """Convert `username` to lowercase."""
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['username'] = ret['username'].lower()
    return ret
```

The above code is just an example. It will return username in lowercase letters. In your case just change the line

> `ret['username'] = ret['username'].lower()`

to

> `ret['username'] = self.validated_data['username']`

Answer (score 0):

[`StringRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its `__str__` method.

For example, the following serializer.

```
class CommentDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'replies',
            'timestamp'
        ]
        ...
```

Comment: Still no username